# SQL : most efficient db for stock quotes

Tags: sql

What is the most efficient way for querying/updating a database containing daily prices for hundreds of stocks

1. each stock having is own table 
   Each stock has the same structure and there is no relation between
2. all stocks combined in one table and indexed on a primary key

Comment: DO you want also to keep track of every variation and keep historical data for stocks, or you only want to keep the last price?

Comment: Any reason at all to have one table pr. stock?

Answer (score 2):

Hundreds of stocks are not so much data.
Hundreds of stocks multiplied for a price detection every minute, means 100Ks records every day and, depending on the historical depth you want to keep, may become some data to manage in the future. The size of a table or, better, a tablespace, affects query performance.

Said that, a table, on the other hand, is an entity representation. A stock, as you state, is an entity and you should put all stocks in one table.

Table indexes are one of many query performance related optimization structures; you should treat separately performance and structure, so keep one table and speed up queries with other tools.

Answer (score 1):

One table per stock means you have the CREATE/DROP tables when companies are listed and delisted.   That's not a good design.  I'd prefer the second design - one table, many stocks.  This assumes that you keep the identical information for each and every stock.

The key is this phrase: "Each stock has the same structure and there is no relation between".  If everything has the same structure, it belongs in one table.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. One table seemed for me also the best solution, but I was afraid having one day a corrupt table and loosing data since the last backup.